# Given $f_{X,Y}$, find out the marginal distributions $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ as well as the expectations $\textbf{E}(X)$ and $\textbf{E}(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The joint probability density function of $(X,Y)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
c(y^{2} - x^{2})e^{-y} & \text{if}\,\,\,-y\leq x \leq y\,\,\text{and}\,\,0 < y < +\infty\\\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

(a) Determine the value of $c$

(b) Determine the marginal probability density functions $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$

(c) Calculate $\textbf{E}(X)$ and $\textbf{E}(Y)$

**MY SOLUTION**

(a) According to the definition of joint probability density function, we have
\begin{align*}
c\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-y}^{y}(y^{2}e^{-y} - x^{2}e^{-y})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y & = c\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2y^{3}e^{-y} - \frac{2y^{3}}{3}e^{-y}\right)\mathrm{d}y\\
& = \frac{c}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}4y^{3}e^{-y}\mathrm{d}y = 8c = 1
\end{align*}

(b) Once again, it results immediately from the definition that
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) & = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\infty}(y^{2}e^{-y} - x^{2}e^{-y})\mathrm{d}y = \frac{2-x^{2}}{8}\\\\
f_{Y}(y) & = \int_{-y}^{y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{8}\int_{-y}^{y}(y^{2}e^{-y} - x^{2}e^{-y})\mathrm{d}x = \frac{y^{3}e^{-y}}{6}
\end{align*}

Where the support of $Y$ is given by $S_{Y} = \textbf{R}_{\geq0}$. Nonetheless, I am still having troubles in calculating the support of $X$. Can someome help me?

**EDIT**

According to Did's observation, the actual probability density function is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \int_{|x|}^{\infty}(y^{2}e^{-y} - x^{2}e^{-y})\mathrm{d}y = \frac{e^{-|x|}(|x| + 1)}{4}
\end{align*}

where the support of $X$ is given by $S_{X} = \textbf{R}$.

(c) Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X) & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_{X}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xe^{-|x|}(|x|+1)\mathrm{d}x = 0\\\\
\textbf{E}(Y) & = \int_{0}^{\infty}yf_{Y}(y)\mathrm{d}Y = \frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{4}e^{-y}\mathrm{d}y = 4
\end{align*}

If there is any additional mistake, do not hesitate to comment.

Comment: Actually, $$f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dy = \frac18\int_{|x|}^\infty(y^2e^{-y} - x^2e^{-y})\mathrm dy = \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Did. I have already edited the answer.

Comment: @Did Why is the lower limit of the integral $|x|$?